# How to get value from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm totally new to PHP.

My question is how to get each group, and each number in following array :

```
$hours=[[["15:00","22:00"]],[["0","0"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]]]
```

traget:

```
["15:00","22:00"]
 
and

"22:00"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide desired output?

Comment: Yes, I done, thank you !

Comment: Try looking into foreach and array keys and values, along with associative arrays.

Comment: Where is this `$hours` array being created?  Why do you have so many nested arrays?

Comment: With this current structure, you'd have to do `$target = $hours[0][0];`.  Then you could do `$target[1]` to get `22:00`.

Comment: What are rules for retrieving `each group` and `number`?

Answer (score 0):

Your can fetch your array with foreach

```
$hours=[[["15:00","22:00"]],[["0","0"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]],[["11:00","22:00"]]];

foreach($hours as $key => $hour) {
    $target = $hour[0];
    var_dump($target);
    var_dump($target[0]);
    var_dump($target[1]);
}
```